# How do you make a bootstrap popover scroll with the navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap popover() being called on a navlink in my fixed header. However, when the user scrolls, the popover is left behind on the page; I would like it to follow the navbar, like dropdown menus do. If you add `position:fixed;` to the popover's style, it does follow the navbar, but then upon scrolling, closing, and reopening the popover, it now have a default position partway down the page. How do you do this properly?

Comment: This seems to be working fine for me... see [my example here](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/4EXwR/1/). There must be something in your code that in messing it up. EDIT: make sure the results pane is wide enough so that the nav is not in mobile mode...

Comment: Hey, thanks. Working backwards from your fiddle, I was able to determine that the problem was I was using an outdated bootstrap.min.js. Simply replacing it with the latest worked fine. Thanks.